# C#. Как работает данный код (касается ключевого слова "return" и рекурсии)?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

```
static int Factorial(int n)
{
    if (n == 0)
        return 1;
    else
        return n * Factorial(--n);
}
```

Конечно, сам код выполняет своё прямое предназначение, а мне нужно понять его логику работы. Вроде бы я понимаю работу рекурсии (и сложной рекурсии) и работу "return", но что-то в этом примере не всё так просто. Конкретно, что меня интересует, почему без первого "return", который оканчивает работу "if" и числа которое он возвращает, было бы невозможно это вычисление? Также я "прошагивал" этот код в "VS" и непонятно, каким вообще образом этот факториал вычислился? Потому что если записать значения, которые вычислялись то это были следующие выражения:

```
5 * 4 = 20
4 * 3 = 12
3 * 2 = 6
2 * 1 = 2
1 * 0 = 0
```

<- эти выражения показал мне "VS", когда шагал код (конечно, "VS" не показывал мне их в том виде, в котором я их написал здесь),
 т. е. первый множитель это у нас "n" второй множитель это - Factorial(--n) и, соответственно, произведение это и есть произведение этих множителей. И спрашиваю, как имея такие произведения и множители удалось корректно выполнить вычисление факториала? Да, я понимаю, что такие вопросы возникли у меня из-за недостаточного знания логики всего этого хозяйства (рекурсии, ключевого слова "return" и т. д.) Д, и потому, собственно, задаю этот вопрос. Надеюсь, понятно изложил суть проблемы)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При вызове Factorial(5) создаётся кадр стека. В этом стеке запоминается значение n, равное пяти.
Происходит сравнение с нулём. Т. к. не равно, происходит переход к ветке else.
Умножение пока что невозможно, оно будет выполнено позже.
Происходит вызов Factorial с уменьшенным на единицу значением n. То есть Factorial(4).
Стек, хранящий значение 5 продолжает существовать.

И всё происходит аналогично: создаётся новый кадр стека, в нём хранится значение n, равное четырём.
Снова ветка else. Умножение пока опять невозможно.
Новый вызов Factorial(3).
Стек, хранящий значение 4 продолжает существовать.

Потом вызов Factorial(2). Потом Factorial(1). Стеки продолжают существовать.

Наконец, вызов Factorial(0).
Снова запоминается значение n в стеке.
Тут наконец-то выполняется ветка if. Возвращается единичка на уровень выше.
Текущий стек с нулём уничтожается.

Вот тут наконец-то выполняется умножение: 1 * 1. Результат возвращается выше.
Стек, хранящий 1 уничтожается.

Так происходит до самого верха: берется возвращённое значение, умножается на хранящееся в текущем кадре стека и передаётся вверх.
Текущий стек уничтожается.

Когда выполнение дойдёт до самого верхнего стека со значением 5, тоже произойдёт умножение и освобождение памяти под стек. Итоговое значение возвращается в вызвавшую функцию.

Comment: Спасибо большое! Невозможно не понять такое объяснение.

Answer (score 3):

Этот код вычисляет факториал рекурсией следующим образом:

```
(5 * (4 * (3 * (2 * (1 * (1))))))
```

Где скобки - это отдельный уровень рекурсии

Answer (score 3):

Это просто условие по которому происходит выход из цикла(любая рекурсия - просто страным образом записаный цикл - большинство оптимизаторов в современных компилятораях сразу же и преобразуют их в обычные циклы), плюс приравнивание 0 к 1(т.к. 1*<любое число> = <любое число>) - если бы мы не приравнивали 0 к 1, то в конце умножили бы всё на 0 и получили бы.. 0

Для числа "5" в вашем примере вычислялось не то, что вы написали выше, а:

```
5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 * 1 = 120
```

Вот во время возврата 1 в первом условии у нас не происходит вызова функици Factorial - на данном шаге цикл прерывается.

Если без рекурсии, то та же самая функция будет выглядеть так:

```
static int Factorial(int n)
{
    int result = 1;

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
        result *= i;

    // result *= 1; - то самое лишнее  умножение на 1. без рекурсии оно нам не нужно

    return result;
}
```